# HTML5 SQLite Db questions

Tags: html, sqlite, web-sql

I've got a couple of questions regarding the Sqlite implementations for HTML5 website.

First of all, I'm trying to use the Synchronous Database calling openDatabaseSync method, but it doesn't seem to work... Someone used it already and could help me ?

Also, I'm struggling a bit trying to process the result return by my database query. I'd like my function to return an array of book, like this :

```
function searchByKeywordId(kw_id, element) {
    cleanSearch();
    element.innerHTML = "No result...";
    var books = new Array();

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT b.BK_TITLE,b.BK_URL, b.BK_THUMBNAIL_URL FROM KEYWORDS k INNER JOIN CATALOG_ITEMS c on k.KW_ID = c.KW_ID INNER JOIN BOOKS b on c.BK_ID = b.BK_ID  WHERE k.KW_ID = ? GROUP BY b.BK_TITLE,b.BK_URL",[kw_id], function (tx, results) {
            if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                var html = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    var bookId = results.rows.item(i).BK_ID;
                    var bookUrl = results.rows.item(i).BK_URL;
                    var bookTitle = results.rows.item(i).BK_TITLE;
                    var bookThumbnailUrl = results.rows.item(i).BK_THUMBNAIL_URL;
                    var book = new Book(bookId,bookTitle,bookUrl,bookThumbnailUrl);
                    books.push(book);

                    /*html += "<div class='x_container' id='calibre:book:" + bookId + "'>";
                    html += "<div class='cover'>";
                    html += "</div></div>";*/
                    html += "<a href='" + bookUrl + "' title=\"" + bookTitle + "\" target='_new'><img src='" + bookThumbnailUrl + "'></a> &nbsp;";
                     }
                //html += "</div>";
                element.innerHTML = html;
            }
        });
    });

    return books; }
```

obviously, adding books within the callback methods doesn't work ... Do you see a way I could achieve that ? So that I would not have to write in the document from my database methods ...

Thanks !

Comment: Added the web-sql tag - note that this is not part of HTML5.

Comment: I understand that the synchronous version methods are not widely supported, even if they are mentioned in the specs. I tested them myself and as a example Chrome v16.0.912.77 does not support the synchronous API (TypeError: "Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'openDatabaseSync'"). About your second question, are you sure the "executeSql" method is not generating and error? add the error callback to it and see if an error is thrown. Also, you could make sure your command is correct by executing it directly in the Resources tab of the Developer Tools in Chrome.

Comment: @Gabobcat openDatabaseSync does exist in Chrome, but in order to use it you must use WebWorkers ... And yes, I'm sure that my query works

Comment: I see. I'm not yet familiarized with WebWorkers, so I can't help you there. As for manipulating the results of your query, what I did once (async scenario) was to create a very simple event notification structure that would fire an event when the success callback got executed. That way I just subscribe to the event somewhere else and execute the result manipulation logic there. Hope that helps you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

On stackoverflow a question with javascript and "doesn't work" in it is usually a missing paren :) However I didn't find one in  your code. I see some suspicious looking syntax around

```
,[kw_id],   << did we really mean an array here, or are we de-referencing something...
```

In any case if that's not a mistake I would start by simplifying things, and not multipurposing your functions.

```
function searchByKeywordId(kw_id, element) {
    cleanSearch();
    var books = new Array();

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT b.BK_TITLE,b.BK_URL, b.BK_THUMBNAIL_URL FROM KEYWORDS k INNER JOIN CATALOG_ITEMS c on k.KW_ID = c.KW_ID INNER JOIN BOOKS b on c.BK_ID = b.BK_ID  WHERE k.KW_ID = ? GROUP BY b.BK_TITLE,b.BK_URL",[kw_id], function (tx, results) {
            if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                var html = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    var bookId = results.rows.item(i).BK_ID;
                    var bookUrl = results.rows.item(i).BK_URL;
                    var bookTitle = results.rows.item(i).BK_TITLE;
                    var bookThumbnailUrl = results.rows.item(i).BK_THUMBNAIL_URL;
                    var book = new Book(bookId,bookTitle,bookUrl,bookThumbnailUrl);
                    books.push(book);

                } // end for loop
            } // end if block
        } // end execute callback
        ); // end executeSql call
    } // end transaction function argument
    ); // end db.transaction call

    return books; 
}
```

Then somewhere that you called this function do something like this:

```
var html="";

for (i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
   html += "<a href='" + books[i].url + "' title=\"" + books[i].title + "\" target='_new'><img src='" + books[i].thumbnailUrl + "'></a> &nbsp;";                                       
}
if (html == "") {
  html = "No result...";
}
element.innerHTML = html; // consider using jQuery here for browser compatability reasons
```

This will simplify debugging your code in firebug or whatever and be more readable. Later IF you need the performance, you can try to recombine and use the existing loop as an optimization... Premature optimization is usually a bad idea. Write clear code that works. Even if you know you should optimize it, get it working and then optimize it after it works (preferably after you've demonstrated that you do in fact need to optimize it).

http://www.flounder.com/optimization.htm

Comment: thanks for your advice. It's really an array, passing arguments for the preparedStatement query. Also the problem in my code, and yours as well is about asyncrhonous statement : the execute callback is asynchronous, so by the time the searchByKeywords method ends, the books array is empty ...